# AWS IAM Policy permissions query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am new to AWS IAM and I am learning to do a security audit for AWS.
For a specific user in AWS the JSON permissions policy looks like this (Account no changed of course)

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",   
"Statement": {       
"Effect": "Allow",       
"Action": "sts:AssumeRole",       
"Resource": [
"arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/APP-NonProd-BC",
"arn:aws:iam::111111111112:role/APP-nonProd-Admins",
"arn:aws:iam::123456789011:role/APP-nonProd-AdminAccess-Role",
"arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/App-NonProd-S3Ops",          
"arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/APY-nonProd-EC2Admin"
]
}
}
```

My question is - Where I can find the permissions for each of the resources. Means, for APP-nonProd-BC resource : what kind of permissions apply? 
For APP-nonprod-AdminAccess-Role : is it really have Admin Access or its just named as AdminAccess and where I Can find the permissions definitions ?

I searched in permissions but not able to find relevent for each of the resources "App-nonProd-BC" or App-nonprod-adminaccess-role" etc. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

These are rules to allow the User to assume these roles. Look within the IAM roles defined and you should be able to see the associated permissions. Permissions can be given to roles, and then user allocated to the roles, so that you can change all the permissions at once and simplify the permission process.

Comment: Sorry. More questions on the subject. Should I look for permissions definitions in which account? the account which is grating the permissions or the account which is accepting the permissions?

Comment: Account which is granting the Permissions since that is where you will change it.